# Spring: Injecting a Scala Constant

Tags: java, spring, scala

Simple *internal* constants, that should not be externalized to properties:

```scala
object InternalConstant {

  val CONSTANT_ONE: Byte = 21
  val CONSTANT_TWO: Byte = 42

}
```

Injecting them as I would with Java:

```xml
<bean id="daBean" class="my.package.DaClass">
    <constructor-arg>
        <util:constant static-field="my.package.InternalConstant.CONSTANT_TWO"/>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

getting a `java.lang.NoSuchFieldException:` `CONSTANT_TWO`

( the package path is *correct* )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because behind the scenes `InternalConstant` is compiled into a class with static `CONSTANT_ONE()` method returning 21, not a field. And calling static methods is possible in Spring with SpEL:

```
<constructor-arg value="#{T(my.package.InternalConstant).CONSTANT_TWO()}"/>
```

Haven't tested it though.

Comment: niice. although it can't be a `static-field` any longer, but this works: <constructor-arg value="#{T(my.package.InternalConstant).CONSTANT_TWO()}"

Comment: "util:constant" does not have a "value" attribute, it should be "constructor-arg" :) So a complete version would read as: <bean id="daBean" class="my.package.DaClass">
    <constructor-arg value="#{T(my.package.InternalConstant).CONSTANT_TWO()}"
</bean>

Comment: Silly me, thanks! BTW feel free to edit other people's posts.

Comment: oh.. ok, did not know if that is considered "normal".. getting up to speed with stackoverflow for the last couple of weeks. Thanks Tomasz!